# Need to deploy the same Codeigniter Code in different Domains but with different Databases

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I have a web application in Codeigniter. Now I want to use the same code and deploy on 100+ different domains.

So I am seeking for a solution where I can use the SAME Code (Stored somewhere on hosting) and connection of it with multiple DB, so that each new DOMAIN will have its own DATABASE but share the same code.

Reason why I need this: any updates done in the code will be applied to all the domains with their own database.

Comment: This sounds like a simple configuration solution. Just define your database config as you normally would with all sites databases pointing to a specific sql server. and then just have different database names per "domain". You'll obviously need a different database configuration file for each domain, or pull in a dynamic database name variable from another configuration file.

Comment: codeigniter is uses oophp.. that mean you can use any php  .. you can use $_SERVER in side of you config file.. so add condition for all of your default or multiple db in your database.php file..

Answer (score 0):

You have to make some minor changes in `config.php` and `database.php` under application/config.

**In config.php**

```
$protocol = isset($_SERVER["HTTPS"]) ? 'https://' : 'http://';
$config['base_url'] =$protocol.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."/";
```

**In database.php**

Put all database connections in conditional statement

```
if ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == 'server1.com') 
{
  $db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
  $db['default']['username'] = 'root';
  $db['default']['password'] = '';
  $db['default']['database'] = 'database1';
}

//for development server
else if ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == 'server2.com') {
  $db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
  $db['default']['username'] = 'root';
  $db['default']['password'] = '';
  $db['default']['database'] = 'database2';
}
```

Except this, all parameters will remain unchanged.

Comment: Thanks dear, It seems that this solution will work super fine with me. Just to ask one more thing.
Just wanted to ask one more thing. How can I redirect www.abc.domain.com to load the code from www.main.domain.com. ( With the same URL as www.abc.domain.com)

Comment: You can park your domains on a single server. I am not very aware of it, but you can follow the link - https://blog.cpanel.com/managing-multiple-domains-from-a-single-cpanel-account/

Answer (score 0):

push your code to Github, add application/config/config.php & application/config/database.php to .gitignore and use git version control on server.

If you make changes in the code, you can do that on your localhost, push to git, and pull from server with git version control. (Don't update the code manually from server to prevent git conflict)